# Google Assistant sdk oauth return url

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

we are trying to integrate google assistant to our embedded device. As per the documentation we can't use limited input device auth process to get access token for assistant sdk.  So I tried to use web application process. But the return url can't be of our public address as per the notes under oauth web client. Amazon alexa doesn't have this restriction. For those who want to use embedded devices which does run Linux it is very difficult to get access token to use google assistant. We are running a server now our embedded device when user types the ip address in the browser it opens a web page which will follow the process to get. Access token. But as the return url .can't have public  address I can't proceed further. Can someone suggest some workaround?

Thanks,
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

[google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.DialogStateIn) now support a bunch of languages, including  french.

Using gRPC, pass `fr-FR` to the `DialogStateIn.language_code`.

If you run the google samples, use the argument `--lang fr-FR`. Example:

```
googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk \
      --project-id <PID> \
      --device-model-id <MID> \
      --lang fr-FR
```